# Finding double integral using change of variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $R$ be a region in $xy$-plane bounded by $y=x^2$ , $y=4x^2$, $xy=1$ and $xy=5$. Then find the value of the integral $\iint _R \frac{y^2}{x} dxdy$

I am not able to get any function of $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ such that I can find limit of the integrals. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: The bounds they give you hands a substitution on a silver platter. $u=\frac{y}{x^2}$, for one. Can you guess the other one?

Comment: @NinadMunshi $xy=v$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = \frac{y}{x^2}$ and $v = xy$. This implies that $\frac{y^2}{x} = uv.$ Your bounds of integration now become $u=1$, $u = 4$, $v=1$ and $v=5$.

Now, all you need is the Jacobian and you can solve!